# Does scala have a lazy evaluating wrapper?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I want to return a wrapper/holder for a result that I want to compute only once and only if the result is actually used. Something like:

```
def getAnswer(question: Question): Lazy[Answer] = ???

println(getAnswer(q).value)
```

This should be pretty easy to implement using `lazy val`:

```
class Lazy[T](f: () => T) {
  private lazy val _result = Try(f())

  def value: T = _result.get
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's already something like this baked into the standard API.

A quick search pointed at [Streams](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) and [`DelayedLazyVal`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.concurrent.DelayedLazyVal) but neither is quite what I'm looking for.

Streams do memoize the stream elements, but it seems like the first element is computed at construction:

```
def compute(): Int = { println("computing"); 1 }

val s1 = compute() #:: Stream.empty
// computing is printed here, before doing s1.take(1)
```

In a similar vein, `DelayedLazyVal` starts computing upon construction, even requires an execution context:

```
val dlv = new DelayedLazyVal(() => 1, { println("started") })
// immediately prints out "started"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why both of the built-ins you mentioned don't meet your needs?

Comment: Added details about why the built-ins don't meet the needs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `scalaz.Need` which I think you'd be able to use for this.